# Relative Path not working in Vaadin Application

Tags: java, vaadin, relative-path

I have a Vaadin application in Eclipse running using Tomcat. I have an external jar file that requires access to a folder "/WordNet-JWI/3.0/dict/".

This works perfectly fine in a normal Java application, where the folder stays in the main project folder, but in a web application, it can't resolve this relative path and gives an error **Dictionary directory does not exist: WordNet-JWI/3.0/dict**

I am fairly new to Web applications and don't know in which folder to put the Wordnet-folder and how to make it available to the external jar for it to run properly.

PS - I put the external jar in /WEB-INF/lib and is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your path the file should be located starting from the root of your partition.
For example if you are using windows it would be C:/WordNet-JWI/3.0/dict/ if you are running the webapp on C:

Mind that on unix the "user" running the Tomcat process must have r/w permission on that folder.

Regards.